# Display webpage on TV SCreen

Tags: display, ethernet, vga

I'm currently doing a project to display a webpage on several LCD Screens across our company, my problem right now is that we currently have no solution to attach a computer to connect to the LCD..

The solution would be something like a device like Raspberry PI for example only to display the website..

It only needs access to a single webpage via ethernet and output by VGA/HDMI. anyone knows an alternative?

Comment: Is the problem that you want the same signal to go to many screens? Just connecting something to a single screen is not very difficult and you can use a computer (a graphics card with HDMI output is cheap), a laptop, a modern phone, a tablet PC...

Comment: 3 screens - 3 different images on them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a VGA/DVI/HDMI splitter to transmit the same video signal between multiple displays, if all of the displays need the same image.  Most of the splitters have a maximum number of displays that they can output to, since the signal power is limited by the video card.  However, you can purchase devices to re-transmit the signal actively (instead of passively), at a higher cost.

If you need a per-LCD webpage, then the Raspberry Pi is the way to go - I don't think you can go much cheaper than a fully-functioning computer for $35 which can output 1080p video.

The advantage to using a single device, however, is that you're not as limited by processing power.  You can have a single, powerful computer display the website contents *if required*, for example if the site has heavy Flash/Silverlight/HTML5 graphics rendering.  However, this is far from necessary for simply displaying a webpage - the Raspberry Pi has more than enough processing power for text/images.

Comment: The problem with raspberry is that it's not atually avaiable.. if I pre-order I would only receive it by August / September... and that makes a non-option